# Connect Cell in Table Grouped View to another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I was working on creating a table grouped view, and I accomplished that (surprisingly). I wanted to be able to connect any given cell in the table and connect it to another unique view. I'm completely stumped on how to do this :/. Here is my code:

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    TableSectionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
    return [TableSectionArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *SectionHeader = nil;

    if (section == 0) {
        SectionHeader = @"Section1";
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        SectionHeader = @"Section2";
    }
    if (section == 2) {
        SectionHeader = @"Section3";
    }
    return SectionHeader;


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        TableContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name1", @"Name2", nil];
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        TableContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name1", @"Name2", nil];
    }
    if (section == 2) {
        TableContentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name1", @"Name2", nil];
    }
    return [TableContentArray count];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [TableContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Comment: You wouldn't be completely stumped if you read Apple's "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" and looked at some of their sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done differently depending on how you reached the current view your on. Basically you need to grab the current instance of the viewController as a whole and then grab the instance of the tableView.

If you segued to the view you are currently on you would do something like:

```
UIPreviousViewController *controller = [self presentingViewController];

UITableViewCell *cell = [controller.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

-Replace the rows and section numbers with whichever ones your trying to grab. The cell will only be readOnly with this method.

-There's a lot of different options depending on your viewController setup(i.e. tabBar viewControllers , navigation stack, etc)

Comment: Sorry for being a noob but: I understand what you mean by grabing the views, but what I am confused about is how to actual go from clicking one of my cells on the TableGroupedView to going to another view. The views the cells will be connected to will each be unique and wont follow a static structure, so I assume they would all need their own view controllers? I am trying to find out how to go from (lets say..) Section 0 Name 1, to a regular view controller? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboard? Just overwrite your didSelectRowAtIndexPath tableView method. Grab the row number in there and then just do a segue to whichever view controller you want to go to with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:self]; They do not all need their own viewControllers unless the look of each one is ENTIRELY different. Your much better off performing the segue and then prepping the view to look however you would like inside the prepareForSegue function